# Architecture for status updates between several services

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, grpc

I have one frontend that's communicating with a main backend that is in turn using services A & B, using gRPC call-response calls. A and B are each responsible for a hardware component they interact with do to some work. Periodically, both hardware components will change statuses, and these statuses need to be forwarded to the frontend.

To solve this, we have 2 ways in our team we are discussing:

1. Establish a gRPC stream between the main backend and service A, and main backend and service B. Whenever a new status from either is available, each service will send a response over the stream to the backend, which in turn will push it to the frontend. The downside is even stronger coupling between services, we would need to manually implement connection re-establishing cause that is not available out of the box for gRPC streams, and when 3rd party customers also want these status updates, it will further complicate the implementation.
2. Have both service A and B push their status updates on a message queue. The backend will then pick them up and push them to the frontend. This would not introduce additional coupling, messages would not get lost when one of the services goes down, and if more parties would be interested in these status updates, all they would need is subscribe to the relevant topic.

I have a clear preference in number 2, but it seems very hard to convince colleagues of this approach. Maybe I am missing something, so for the sake of objectivity, I wonder what your thoughts are on either approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

approach #2 seems to be the more reasonable. It would introduce less coupling between the services and increase the overall reliability.
Semi-realtime updates can be achieved using a fast streaming service, like Kafka for example. I would use it instead of RabbitMQ as the latter has normally lower throughput due to extra processing in its routing system.

Comment: I agree with using Kafka, throughput is so much higher than RabbitMQ. I've used Kafka in the past where throughput demands were so much higher. Our system is very small and doesn't even involve multiple users. We're talking about a small system in a machine. Reliability, stability and security are major concerns, performance in terms of high traffic is definitely not. So, in most cases I would be completely on board. For our particular use case, we can definitely get away with RabbitMQ. Even if normal queues don't suffice, I would try Rabbitmq streams before going for Kafka to avoid complexity

Comment: if you're already comfortable with Rabbitmq streams, then go for it. One thing to consider though before you commit to it, is the number of events you would receive from those machines. Concurrent users are not an issue in your case, I presume.

Comment: No, indeed, that's not an issue. Updates would be relatively infrequent (we're not even talking 1 update per second, and often times not even 1 per minute). One machine has one user interface, to be controlled by one person. Of course, there's a possibility in the future that 3rd party components are interested in these updates. In that case, they can simply subscribe to the relevant queues or topics.

Comment: then rabbitmq is a good choice :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend, first of all, creating a list of requirements and caveats.  You don't need to publish them.  Personally, I always perform this exercise even if I never publish them, to be sure I have all the issues in mind.

You mentioned a concern about the complications of status to 3rd parties but didn't mention the concern with solution #2. I think that is the part where the solution weighs heavily in favor of solution #2.

RabbitMQ enables to easy implementation of the following features:

```
group chats
message delivery check
receiving a message from the user while offline
receiving a message on all client applications at the same time (iOS, Android)
preventing unnecessary messages sending
message delivery optimization in case of disconnection from RabbitMQ, e.g. during Internet cut-off
```

PS. Are you thinking of creating an API for the backends to post status to the front end in solution one?

Comment: Yes, those requirements have definitely been gathered. It's still a discussion though. I've used RabbitMQ and other brokers in several architectures for over a decade now, so I'm pretty familiar with these kinds of problems. In both cases, the backend will push the status updates to the frontend using socketIO.

Comment: Is this a discussion along the lines of streaming because you need real-time status vs. publish/subscription messaging?

Comment: We do need quasi realtime updates. Updates can be quite rare to come in, maybe sometimes not even being sent for minutes. But if they occur, we need them published quite fast.

Comment: I assume the primary discussion is when comparing streaming data vs. message queues. I also make the assumption that using the process to stream data is all about processing in near real-time and/or the requirement to process large amounts of data.  It is this kind of background that helps the architectural decisions.

Comment: I am completely revamping my comment, in case you've already seen my initial command.  I have read your initial problem statement once again. Is the argument for using streaming communications between the main backend and services A and B because you already use streaming services, so why not communicate that way down to the services?

Comment: Not really about big amounts of data. These status updates are very small. They are also infrequent enough as to not overload the broker to any extent so not being fast enough to guarantee realtime behavior is not a concern. If it is, instead of normal queues, rabbitmq streams can be used. For me, the most important criteria besides the above is to promote loose coupling as much as possible, and benefit from a broker to have no loss of messages and not having to worry about temporary disconnects from downstream services. Also, the way the backend uses services A and B, is NOT with streaming.

Comment: So the backend just communicates with A and B with normal call and response gRPC calls

Comment: Now I get it.  You are currently using calls, and something is requiring a switch to GPRC streaming.  I hope I understand this correctly.  And since you are changing things up, then you'd prefer Rabbit MQ messaging for apparent reasons. The prevailing argument against using RabbitMQ is why you should change the architecture when gPRC is already in place, and it is simply a matter of recoding into a streaming service definition between the backend and services A and B.
Am I getting this right?

Comment: Yeah you're very close there. GRPC was already used for calls from backend to the downstream services. Then the functionality of status updates became a requirement, and there simply 2 possible approaches there. We will always keep using gRPC for these kinds of call-response calls. It's a nice technology. The question now is simply about what's most suitable for status updates that will be pushed out by a few downstream services.

Comment: Well then, I concur that option #2 is the best approach, not just because of the loose coupling and no loss of messages (that is, as long as rabbitMQ is healthy), but you now have options with certain status messages that can go to slack, or email, or other messaging platforms.  

That said, I'll add the caveat that I don't know the full architecture. 

But we are missing the point.  You don't need concurrence.  You need convincing points for colleagues.  I'll have to think about that

Comment: Well, this is not the first time I've done this. I architected quite a few big systems, alone or with other architects, in several big companies, and have seen the consequences of our architectural choices over the years. Some roads lead to architectures that are way easier to evolve, others lead you to paint yourself in corners. This is the first time 2 choices with very clear cut benefits and downsides lead to such contention.

Comment: It sounds like you know the logical reasons to run with RabbitMQ.  I don't know if I can help with the convincing.  Other than, the key ingredient, RabbitMQ promotes a decoupled architecture, making it easier to replace or upgrade individual services without impacting the entire system and RabbitMQ can be more cost-effective compared to maintaining gRPC for every service.

Comment: Well, one pushback I saw is that it's not possible to differentiate between a service not sending updates over the queue because it has none, or that service being down or not-functioning. When a constant connection is kept open, when there's issues with it, the consuming service interested in the status updates would "know". I'd say it's not the responsibility of a service to monitor the health of another, unless that's it's sole purpose as a watchdog. But there are 3rd party solutions for that. And to solve the actual issue, there's business logic you can implement to solve it.